# Jquery Tabs - reload/refresh content on tab select, how?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, refresh, reload

I've been researching for several hours now and I can't seem to figure this out.  Although I have seen several topics similar to this, I just can't seem to make sense of it — bare in mind I know next to nothing about jquery.

I was able to get running following this tutorial: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/

It does EXACTLY what I am looking for, BUT I need to be able to reload the tab content or page when I select between the tabs back and forth — of course after the reload I want to still be under the current tab.

Why?

I am using this method as a selector for sorting my comments (newest posted and highest rated). Problem is, the process or functions (comment replies) are loaded on the default tab and when I select to the other tab, any links I click there will only show on the original tab.

What code can I add to reload content so that clicking on tabs reloads the process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax or dynamic content you generated before.

```
$(".tabs a").on("click", function() {
    var curTabId = $(this).attr("href");
    $(curTabId).load('content.html');
    //or $(curTabId).html(yourGeneratedContent);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still a little lost.  Do I just add that with the rest of the code? Also what do you mean by "content.html" or yourgeneratedcontent?  What do I put here....I am using wordpress btw